# Why is jQuery ajax running twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have read all the SO answers and they seem to involve an event handler, which is not the case with my situation.

**JS**

```
$(function () {
    var data = {};
    data.action = "getUser"
    ajax('post', 'php/login.php', data, success, "Initialization error: ", 'json', false);
    function success(result) {
        if (result) {
            var data = {};
            window.localStorage.setItem("user-id", result.userid);
            console.log("userid=" + result.userid);
            console.log("username=" + result.username);
            console.log("user-id from storage=" + window.localStorage.getItem("user-id"));
        } else {
            var msg = "Welcome to the Writer's Tryst. Create an account to participate as a writer or enabler.";
            showMessage(1, msg);
            console.log(msg);
        }
    }
})
function formatError(errmsg, err, xhrmsg) {
    return errmsg + (err.length ? err + " " : '')  + (xhrmsg.length ? xhrmsg : '');
}
function ajax(method, url, data, success_callback, errmsg, dataType, cache, processData, contentType) {
    cache = typeof cache !== 'undefined' ? false : true;
    processData = typeof processData !== 'undefined' ? false : true;
    contentType = typeof contentType !== 'undefined' ? false : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8";
    dataType = typeof dataType !== 'undefined' ? dataType: 'text';
    $.ajax({
        type: method,
        url:  url,
        data: data,
        cache: cache,
        processData: processData,
        contentType: contentType,
        dataType: dataType
    }).done(function (result, success, xhr) {
        success_callback(result);
    }).fail(function (xhr, desc, err) {
        var msg = formatError((errmsg ? errmsg : ""), err, xhr.responseText);
        showMessage(0, msg);
        console.log(msg);
    });
}
function showMessage(errorType, msg) {
    switch (errorType) {
        case 0:
            $("#message").text(msg).css({ 'color': 'white', 'background-color': 'red', 'display': 'block' });
            break;
        case 1:
            $("#message").text(msg).css({ 'color': 'white', 'background-color': 'green', 'display': 'block' });
            break;
        default:
            $("#message").text(msg).css({ 'color': 'white', 'background-color': 'orange', 'display': 'block' });
            break;
    }
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');
}
$(document).on("keypress click", function(){$("#message").css({'display': 'none'})})
```

**console.log**

> userid=52 username=ront user-id from storage=52
>
> userid=52 username=ront user-id from storage=52

Comment: Why is `function success(result) {` in dom ready handler?

Comment: it wouldn't matter if it is or not, since it gets passed to ajax function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the problem before where it looks like it's being sent out twice because of two console entries, but when you check the network tab there's only one request.

Try going to the network tab, clearing everything with the red circle/slash button in the upper left, then triggering the request again and see if two entries show up.